# How to disable access to the microphone in VMware workstation?

Tags: audio, vmware, microphone, vmware-workstation

When I add a sound card to the guest virtual machine it adds access to both input and output devices. It is possible to add access only to the output device and block access to the microphone?
Thanks in advance!